# How can I Integrate large trigonometric expressions more efficiently?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

I have a requirement to integrate some large symbolic expressions containing products of trigonometric functions. A single integration is averaging 7 minutes, and I have 2628 expressions to integrate, so it will take 13 days to complete unless I can speed it up.

Here is an example:

```
expr = c14 (a0+a1 Cos[n x]+a3 Cos[2 n x]+a5 Cos[3 n x]+a7 Cos[4 n x]+a2 Sin[n x]+a4 Sin[2 n x]+a6 Sin[3 n x]+a8 Sin[4 n x]) (e1 Cos[n x]+e3 Cos[2 n x]+e5 Cos[3 n x]+e7 Cos[4 n x]+e2 Sin[n x]+e4 Sin[2 n x]+e6 Sin[3 n x]+e8 Sin[4 n x])+c44 (e1 Cos[n x]+e3 Cos[2 n x]+e5 Cos[3 n x]+e7 Cos[4 n x]+e2 Sin[n x]+e4 Sin[2 n x]+e6 Sin[3 n x]+e8 Sin[4 n x])^2+c66 (j0+j1 Cos[n x]+j3 Cos[2 n x]+j5 Cos[3 n x]+j7 Cos[4 n x]+j2 Sin[n x]+j4 Sin[2 n x]+j6 Sin[3 n x]+j8 Sin[4 n x])^2+c11 (1/2 (h0+h1 Cos[n x]+h3 Cos[2 n x]+h2 Sin[n x]+h4 Sin[2 n x])^2+3/2 (a0+a1 Cos[n x]+a3 Cos[2 n x]+a5 Cos[3 n x]+a7 Cos[4 n x]+a2 Sin[n x]+a4 Sin[2 n x]+a6 Sin[3 n x]+a8 Sin[4 n x])^2+1/2 (d0+d1 Cos[n x]+d3 Cos[2 n x]+d5 Cos[3 n x]+d7 Cos[4 n x]+d2 Sin[n x]+d4 Sin[2 n x]+d6 Sin[3 n x]+d8 Sin[4 n x])^2)+c14 ((b0+b1 Cos[n x]+b3 Cos[2 n x]+b5 Cos[3 n x]+b7 Cos[4 n x]+b2 Sin[n x]+b4 Sin[2 n x]+b6 Sin[3 n x]+b8 Sin[4 n x]) (d0+d1 Cos[n x]+d3 Cos[2 n x]+d5 Cos[3 n x]+d7 Cos[4 n x]+d2 Sin[n x]+d4 Sin[2 n x]+d6 Sin[3 n x]+d8 Sin[4 n x])+2 (a0+a1 Cos[n x]+a3 Cos[2 n x]+a5 Cos[3 n x]+a7 Cos[4 n x]+a2 Sin[n x]+a4 Sin[2 n x]+a6 Sin[3 n x]+a8 Sin[4 n x]) (e1 Cos[n x]+e3 Cos[2 n x]+e5 Cos[3 n x]+e7 Cos[4 n x]+e2 Sin[n x]+e4 Sin[2 n x]+e6 Sin[3 n x]+e8 Sin[4 n x])+(h0+h1 Cos[n x]+h3 Cos[2 n x]+h2 Sin[n x]+h4 Sin[2 n x]) (g0+g1 Cos[n x]+g3 Cos[2 n x]+g5 Cos[3 n x]+g7 Cos[4 n x]+g2 Sin[n x]+g4 Sin[2 n x]+g6 Sin[3 n x]+g8 Sin[4 n x]))+c12 (1/2 (b0+b1 Cos[n x]+b3 Cos[2 n x]+b5 Cos[3 n x]+b7 Cos[4 n x]+b2 Sin[n x]+b4 Sin[2 n x]+b6 Sin[3 n x]+b8 Sin[4 n x])^2+1/2 (e1 Cos[n x]+e3 Cos[2 n x]+e5 Cos[3 n x]+e7 Cos[4 n x]+e2 Sin[n x]+e4 Sin[2 n x]+e6 Sin[3 n x]+e8 Sin[4 n x])^2+1/2 (g0+g1 Cos[n x]+g3 Cos[2 n x]+g5 Cos[3 n x]+g7 Cos[4 n x]+g2 Sin[n x]+g4 Sin[2 n x]+g6 Sin[3 n x]+g8 Sin[4 n x])^2)+c13 (1/2 (c0+c1 Cos[n x]+c3 Cos[2 n x]+c2 Sin[n x]+c4 Sin[2 n x])^2+1/2 (f0+f1 Cos[n x]+f3 Cos[2 n x]+f5 Cos[3 n x]+f7 Cos[4 n x]+f2 Sin[n x]+f4 Sin[2 n x]+f6 Sin[3 n x]+f8 Sin[4 n x])^2+1/2 (j0+j1 Cos[n x]+j3 Cos[2 n x]+j5 Cos[3 n x]+j7 Cos[4 n x]+j2 Sin[n x]+j4 Sin[2 n x]+j6 Sin[3 n x]+j8 Sin[4 n x])^2);

Integrate[expr, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

`n` is an integer, if that helps.

How can I compute these integrals more efficiently?

Take case with this example too:

```
a12 = Cos[n x] (c14 (a0+a1 Cos[n x]+a3 Cos[2 n x]+a5 Cos[3 n x]+a7 Cos[4 n x]+a2 Sin[n x]+a4 Sin[2 n x]+a6 Sin[3 n x]+a8 Sin[4 n x]) (e1 Cos[n x]+e3 Cos[2 n x]+e5 Cos[3 n x]+e7 Cos[4 n x]+e2 Sin[n x]+e4 Sin[2 n x]+e6 Sin[3 n x]+e8 Sin[4 n x])+c44 (e1 Cos[n x]+e3 Cos[2 n x]+e5 Cos[3 n x]+e7 Cos[4 n x]+e2 Sin[n x]+e4 Sin[2 n x]+e6 Sin[3 n x]+e8 Sin[4 n x])^2+c66 (j0+j1 Cos[n x]+j3 Cos[2 n x]+j5 Cos[3 n x]+j7 Cos[4 n x]+j2 Sin[n x]+j4 Sin[2 n x]+j6 Sin[3 n x]+j8 Sin[4 n x])^2+c11 (1/2 (h0+h1 Cos[n x]+h3 Cos[2 n x]+h2 Sin[n x]+h4 Sin[2 n x])^2+3/2 (a0+a1 Cos[n x]+a3 Cos[2 n x]+a5 Cos[3 n x]+a7 Cos[4 n x]+a2 Sin[n x]+a4 Sin[2 n x]+a6 Sin[3 n x]+a8 Sin[4 n x])^2+1/2 (d0+d1 Cos[n x]+d3 Cos[2 n x]+d5 Cos[3 n x]+d7 Cos[4 n x]+d2 Sin[n x]+d4 Sin[2 n x]+d6 Sin[3 n x]+d8 Sin[4 n x])^2)+c14 ((b0+b1 Cos[n x]+b3 Cos[2 n x]+b5 Cos[3 n x]+b7 Cos[4 n x]+b2 Sin[n x]+b4 Sin[2 n x]+b6 Sin[3 n x]+b8 Sin[4 n x]) (d0+d1 Cos[n x]+d3 Cos[2 n x]+d5 Cos[3 n x]+d7 Cos[4 n x]+d2 Sin[n x]+d4 Sin[2 n x]+d6 Sin[3 n x]+d8 Sin[4 n x])+2 (a0+a1 Cos[n x]+a3 Cos[2 n x]+a5 Cos[3 n x]+a7 Cos[4 n x]+a2 Sin[n x]+a4 Sin[2 n x]+a6 Sin[3 n x]+a8 Sin[4 n x]) (e1 Cos[n x]+e3 Cos[2 n x]+e5 Cos[3 n x]+e7 Cos[4 n x]+e2 Sin[n x]+e4 Sin[2 n x]+e6 Sin[3 n x]+e8 Sin[4 n x])+(h0+h1 Cos[n x]+h3 Cos[2 n x]+h2 Sin[n x]+h4 Sin[2 n x]) (g0+g1 Cos[n x]+g3 Cos[2 n x]+g5 Cos[3 n x]+g7 Cos[4 n x]+g2 Sin[n x]+g4 Sin[2 n x]+g6 Sin[3 n x]+g8 Sin[4 n x]))+c12 (1/2 (b0+b1 Cos[n x]+b3 Cos[2 n x]+b5 Cos[3 n x]+b7 Cos[4 n x]+b2 Sin[n x]+b4 Sin[2 n x]+b6 Sin[3 n x]+b8 Sin[4 n x])^2+1/2 (e1 Cos[n x]+e3 Cos[2 n x]+e5 Cos[3 n x]+e7 Cos[4 n x]+e2 Sin[n x]+e4 Sin[2 n x]+e6 Sin[3 n x]+e8 Sin[4 n x])^2+1/2 (g0+g1 Cos[n x]+g3 Cos[2 n x]+g5 Cos[3 n x]+g7 Cos[4 n x]+g2 Sin[n x]+g4 Sin[2 n x]+g6 Sin[3 n x]+g8 Sin[4 n x])^2)+c13 (1/2 (c0+c1 Cos[n x]+c3 Cos[2 n x]+c2 Sin[n x]+c4 Sin[2 n x])^2+1/2 (f0+f1 Cos[n x]+f3 Cos[2 n x]+f5 Cos[3 n x]+f7 Cos[4 n x]+f2 Sin[n x]+f4 Sin[2 n x]+f6 Sin[3 n x]+f8 Sin[4 n x])^2+1/2 (j0+j1 Cos[n x]+j3 Cos[2 n x]+j5 Cos[3 n x]+j7 Cos[4 n x]+j2 Sin[n x]+j4 Sin[2 n x]+j6 Sin[3 n x]+j8 Sin[4 n x])^2))
```

Comment: Upload your matrix (as a .nb file) to a repository and provide a link.  A sub-matrix is good too.

Comment: @QuantumDot,  Hi, thanks for your help.  But I didn't understand. Please explain it in detail. Thanks

Comment: You need to supply a couple of examples of the integrations, otherwise we don't know why it's so slow.

Comment: @SimonWoods, N2matrix(1,1) = ((6*a0**2*c11 + 3*a1**2*c11 + 3*a2**2*c11 + 3*a3**2*c11 + 3*a4**2*c11 + 3*a5**2*c11 + 3*a6**2*c11 + 3*a7**2*c11 + 3*a8**2*c11 + 2*b0**2*c12 + b1**2*c12 + b2**2*c12 + b3**2*c12 + b4**2*c12 + b5**2*c12 + b6**2*c12 + b7**2*c12 + b8**2*c12 + 2*c0**2*c13 + c1**2*c13 + c13*c2**2 + c13*c3**2 + c13*c4**2 + 4*b0*c14*d0 + 2*c11*d0**2 + 2*b1*c14*d1 + c11*d1**2 + 2*b2*c14*d2 + c11*d2**2 + 2*b3*c14*d3  )*Pi)/8        This expression is too much long, I could not print the reuslts. This is the result of integration of one element.

Comment: "all elements contain quadratic expressions of trigonometric functions". Is there a pattern that can be generalized into a single or perhaps a few forms that can be integrated to reduce the number of integrations required.

Comment: My Problem contain Cos(n*x)^2 Sin(n*x)^2 terms. N is integer here.

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon, No, they cannot be generalized into even few forms.

Comment: What we need is an example of the original `Integrate` expression, not the result. And please add additional information to the *question*, not as comments. There is an "edit" button under the question for that purpose.

Comment: @Simon Woods, Hi, I have shown the first element of my matrix which need to be integrated. It has a quadratic expression of trigonometric expressions as you can see above.

Comment: Is it a definite integral or indefinite?  If definite, what is the interval?

Comment: Ya.. It is a definite integral over the interval x=0 to 2*Pi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your integrand(s), when expanded, consist of terms that are constants times zero, one or two factors of sine or cosine.  The terms can be integrated symbolically and stored as rules.  It will be convenient to find the average value and multiply by `2 Pi` at the end.  (This will automatically handle constant terms without a special rule.)  Thanks to [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) for a much simplified set of rules.

```
Clear[a, b];
iRules = {(Cos | Sin)[_]^2 -> 1/2, (Cos | Sin)[_] -> 0};

ia11 = 2 Pi Expand[a11] /. iRules; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.010274, Null}  *)
```

It's a lot faster:

```
evalRules = {   (* assumes  n  is an  Integer *)
  Cos[(a_Integer: 1) n Pi] :> (-1)^a,
  Sin[(b_Integer: 1) n Pi] :> 0
  };
ja11 = Integrate[a11, {x, 0, 2 Pi}] /. evalRules; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {177.270803, Null}  *)
```

And it gives the same result, provided the assumptions inherent in `evalRules` are correct:

```
ia11 == Expand[ja11] // Simplify
(*  True  *)
```

---

**Update:**
Here's another way, about 20 times slower than `iRules`, but 1000 times faster than `Integrate`.  It's a similar idea, but it should work on general products of sines and cosines.  It assumes that sines and cosines are the only functions in the integrands.

```
ka11 = 2 Pi Expand[TrigToExp@a11] /. E^_ -> 0; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.205734, Null}  *)

ka11 == Expand[ja11 /. evalRules] // Simplify
(*  True  *)
```

Or, sparked by a comment by the OP, more complicated combinations of sines and cosines can be fairly quickly simplified with `TrigReduce`.

```
2 Pi TrigReduce[a11] /. iRules; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.086483, Null}  *)
```

---

**Original rules**

```
iRules =(*Dispatch@*)
 {Cos[(a_Integer: 1) n x] Sin[(a_Integer: 1) n x] ->
   Integrate[Cos[a n x] Sin[a n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi),
  Cos[(a_Integer: 1) n x] Sin[(b_Integer: 1) n x] /; a == -b -> 
   Integrate[Cos[a n x] Sin[-a n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi),
  Cos[(a_Integer: 1) n x] Sin[(b_Integer: 1) n x] -> 
   Integrate[Cos[a n x] Sin[b n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi),
  Sin[(a_Integer: 1) n x] Sin[(b_Integer: 1) n x] -> 
   Integrate[Cos[a n x] Sin[b n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi),
  Cos[(a_Integer: 1) n x] Cos[(b_Integer: 1) n x] -> 
   Integrate[Cos[a n x] Sin[b n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi),
  Cos[(a_Integer: 1) n x]^2 -> 
   Integrate[Cos[a n x]^2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi),
  Sin[(b_Integer: 1) n x]^2 -> 
   Integrate[Sin[b n x]^2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi),
  Cos[(a_Integer: 1) n x] -> 
   Integrate[Cos[a n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi),
  Sin[(b_Integer: 1) n x] -> 
   Integrate[Sin[b n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi)};
```

**Some remarks on the code:**  Note that the rule in `iRules` are `Rule` (`->`) not `RuleDelayed` (`:>`).  This means that the integrals will be performed when `iRules` are defined instead of delayed until the application of `iRules`.  Therefore the pattern symbols `a` and `b` must be cleared of any values.  If that is not possible, then use other symbols or put in a `Module`  (`Module[{a, b}, iRules = {...}]`).

[`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html) did not speed things up for me.  That may change if the list of integration rules were to grow much larger.

Comment: +1 Same approach I took, though since n is an integer I didn't bother with `Integrate` at all. Just `Expand[2 Pi expr]/.{(Cos|Sin)[_]^2 -> 1/2, (Cos|Sin)[_] -> 0}`

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks.  And duh.  I started from the OP's comment that he had products of squares.  The adjustment was through cut-and-paste, instead of rethinking the problem.  Your approach is how I do integrals in spherical coordinates in my head when teaching vector calculus.  (I teach it to the students, too.  As [Penn & Teller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8osRaFTtgHo) have shown, magic is even more fascinating you can see what's going on.)

Comment: @SimonWoods That is a superior way, even if conceptually the same, and I felt the site deserved the best answer.  So I included it and converted the answer to CW.  (Or you could answer, and I'll delete.)

Comment: No, please don't delete your original. I think it's good to keep it as it shows how you would approach similar problems in cases where the integrals aren't trivial.

Comment: Thanks Simon woods and Michael E2. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SimonWoods, I have supplied the a12 element of my matrix.  With your method, Expand[2 Pi a12]/.{(Cos|Sin)[_]^2 -> 1/2, (Cos|Sin)[_] -> 0} Results is: 2 ((3 a0 a1 c11)/2+(b0 b1 c12)/2+(c0 c1 c13)/2+(b1 c14 d0)/2+(b0 c14 d1)/2+(c11 d0 d1)/2+(3 a0 c14 e1)/2+(c13 f0 f1)/2+(c12 g0 g1)/2+(c14 g1 h0)/2+(c14 g0 h1)/2+(c11 h0 h1)/2+(c13 j0 j1)/2+c66 j0 j1) \[Pi]   whereas True result does not match with it.

Comment: I have found another way          Simplify[Integrate[TrigReduce[a12], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], 
 Element[n, Integers]] which gives me True result

Comment: With use of TrigReduce, Total time of 13 days will reduce to 5 days. Atleast I wont be having any doubt about my results, because with using iRules that were defined here may or may not give me the accurate results.

Comment: @Amandeep The only problem is that your other entries have different products of sines and cosines than `a11`.  You need to expand the list of rules `iRules` to include all cases.

Comment: @MichaelE2,  I have tried TrigReduce[2 Pi a12]/.{(Cos|Sin)[]^2 -> 1/2, (Cos|Sin)[] -> 0}  It gave me correct results as TrigReduce rewrites products and powers of trigonometric functions in expr in terms of trigonometric functions with combined arguments.  So Rule applies here well.

Comment: @MichaelE2,  I am trying to see if my results will be accurate with TrigReduce on different elements. if it will come out to be true, it will be a great success for all of us. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: @Amandeep  See the update.  It might get the time down to under an hour.  There is a way to construct programmatically a list of rules that would handle all the entries in the matrix, but I doubt it is worth it.  While applying the rules would be faster, constructing the list of rules might not be.

Comment: @Amandeep OK, `TrigReduce` might be just as good or better.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Yes It is. TrigReduce is much better way. It reduces all products and squares of trigonometric functions into Cos[a*n*x] and Sin[b*n*x] which by rules, equals to zero. In this way, My whole time reduces within one hour. Thanks to you sir. Thanks a lot. and also to Sir, Simon Woods