# numerical integration question

Tags: numerical-integration

The actual expressions is quite complicated so I will use a trivial example.

Let

```
In[36]:= f[u_] := 1/3 - (5/18)*(Cos[u]*a[1] + Sin[u]*b[1])^2
```

Then

```
In[37]:= Integrate[f[u], {u, 0, 2*Pi}]

Out[37]= 1/18 \[Pi] (12 - 5 (a[1]^2 + b[1]^2))
```

In the actual situation I have complicated integrands of u like above multiplied by various combinations of a[i], b[i] (i=1,2,3).
So, I have to perform numerical integration.

What I want is to "persuade" Mathematica to make the numerical integration without bothering that a[i], b[i] do not have numerical values.
That is, I want somehow the output of

```
NIntegrate[f[u], {u, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

to be something like

```
2.0944 - 0.872665 a[1]^2 - 0.872665 b[1]^2
```

Is it possible to do so?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related, perhaps: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65760/how-can-i-integrate-large-trigonometric-expressions-more-efficiently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on the simple example:

```
vars = Array[a, 1]~Join~Array[b, 1];
FromCoefficientRules[
 MapAt[
  NIntegrate[
    #,
    {u, 0, 2 Pi},
    AccuracyGoal -> 14] &,
  CoefficientRules[f[u], vars],
  {All, -1}],
 vars]
(*
  2.0944 - 0.872665 a[1]^2 - 1.3713*10^-17 a[1] b[1] - 0.872665 b[1]^2
*)

Chop[%]
(*
  2.0944 - 0.872665 a[1]^2 - 0.872665 b[1]^2
*)
```