# Numerical integration with symbolic coefficients

Tags: numerical-integration

Thanks to Michael and its reply [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67673/numerical-integration-question)

I managed to deal with some of the more complicated integrals. But still there are some even more complicated ones.

Let give a specific example.

```
fun := (-3 + 18*Sin[u]^2*Sin[X]^2 + 21*Sin[u]^4*Sin[X]^4 - 
    4*Cos[u]^2*Cos[Y]^2*
          (-3 + 5*Sin[u]^2*Sin[X]^2) + 
    40*Cos[u]*Cos[X]*Cos[Y]*Sin[u]^3*Sin[X]^2*Sin[Y] + 
        12*Cos[X]^2*Sin[u]^2*Sin[Y]^2 - 
    5*Sin[u]^4*Sin[2*X]^2*Sin[Y]^2 - 6*Cos[X]*Sin[2*u]*Sin[2*Y])/
     ((-1 + 7*Sin[u]^2*Sin[X]^2)*(9 - 14*Sin[u]^2*Sin[X]^2 + 
      41*Sin[u]^4*Sin[X]^4))
```

Once again I want to "persuade" Mathematica to make the numerical integration

```
NIntegrate[fun, {u, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

without bothering that Cos[X], Sin[X] etc do not have numerical values.
Is is possible to do so?

Comment: You probably can't do it blindly. For example `Integrate[fun /. {X -> Pi/2, Y -> 0}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]` does not converge

Comment: maybe @MichaelE2 should elaborate on his other answer, but it works because that example can be broken into a sum of integrals with the symbolic constants pulled out of each.  "no chance" that will work with this complicated expression.

Comment: In your previous post the symbolic coefficients were scalar factors of the terms, so we could apply the rule `$\int c\,f(u)\;du = c \int f(u)\;du$.  In this case, they are no longer scalar factors but involved in the terms in the denominator.  I dislike saying something is impossible merely because I can't think of a way, but I think this goes beyond that.  I do think it's impossible.

Comment: FWIW, the integrand is a rational function of sine and cosine, so theoretically it can be integrated exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I can't go blindly as belisarius mentioned.